# UITableView load image async - where to put loading code?

Tags: ios, swift, image, tableview

I am learning iOS and swift development and have a question about loading images asynchronous in a UITableView.

Where should I put the dataTask? should it go in CellForRow at index path or should it be in the UITableViewCell subclass?

Either way it seems to fire off 10's of connections when I scroll quickly, how would I get around this and cancel downloading when scrolling the cell off the screen.

Comment: Rather than cancelling the download, Use a framwork like SDWebImage (or build you own cache using NSCache). That way you will have he image when the cell scrolls back into view

Comment: @Paulw11 don't want to use a framework to be honest i want to understand the fundamentals rather than just using something I don't know anything about.